# Is there a better way to check for expired SESSIONS when using JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I've only been using `JQuery` for a few weeks. And in this short time I've noticed that, when a SESSION expires, my Login page loads inside the already-loaded document. This was never an issue until I started using JQuery. So I'm thinking that, since I've rewritten all my documents for JQuery to make the calls to PHP, my lone SESSION check is being pulled into the JQuery PHP calls instead of redirecting to the login page. When it does this, a quick page refresh will send the user to the login page. But it sure looks cheesy.

So, my thinking on this (and I hope I'm wrong) is to put

```
if ($_SESSION["memberid"] == "") {
header("Location: wslogin.php");
exit();
}
```

inside every PHP block called by JQuery. Maybe this wld be what's now needed since I'm using JQuery. Before JQuery, all my work was inside `<form>` tags, and the pages reloaded with every action. And an ended SESSION was **always** sent to the login page. I'm not the best explainer in the world, but I hope someone understands this and has a solution. Thanks.

Comment: you can set up an interval based request just to check session with ajax ... and react accordingly if it is expired or close to expiration. Would allow putting up a dialog for user to know what is going on

Comment: @charlietfl - not a bad idea. I suppose I cld make a function that wld be called every time there's a call to JQuery that wld do nothing but check the SESSION. Not bad at all. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send 401-Unauthorized status code from requested page if session expired. Then capture status code in your client AJAX call.

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
  data: {},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    // do whatever here
  },
  type: 'post',
  url: 'load_data.php',
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // XMLHttpRequest.responseText has your json string
    // XMLHttpRequest.status has the 401 status code
    if (XMLHttpRequest.status === 401) {
      location.href = 'login.php';
    }
  }
});
```

**PHP**

```
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', true, 401);
```

**Reference**

[HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)

Comment: Nice code. Like I said, I'm new to JQuery, but I understand most of your solution. The structure of your `ajax` is a little different from the way I learned it (through a few youtube videos). But I think I get it okay. Thanks, Pradeep Sanjaya. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Session, with php control your session

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 120)) {
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    header('location:logout.php');
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('location:logout.php');
}
?>
```

Simply you may keep this on header of your template page so every time php check the session timing even you may improve this...

Comment: Rafiq: This is a nice solution. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Rafiq: His question was not about session handling. His question was about if he tries to load a part of the document from a AJAX request and if he has implemented session handling as per your session handling, then it receives the login page content instead of requested content.

Comment: yes dear @PradeepSanjaya you are right, this answer will help any new php students for their first project it helped me once

Comment: Rafiq: Your answer was helpful to me because I hadn't been `unsetting` or `destroying` when a `session` expired. Together with Pradeep Sanjaya's answer and yours, I have a better understanding of what's needed here. Thank you both.

Comment: @Landslyde you are weclome